# Scala instantiate common val on two classes with same parent

Tags: scala

I have two classes that extend the same trait :

```
trait Event {
  val propertyCommon : String = ""
}

case class EventA(propertyA : String) extends Event
case class EventB(propertyB : String) extends Event
```

Now I instantiate my classes in a List :

```
myList : List[Event] = List(EventA("a"),EventB("b"))
```

What I want to do is to instantiate after the common property, as if there was a copy method in my trait :

```
myList.map(_.copy(propertyCommon = "Something"))
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: This is a weird way to define a case class; if you give us a bit more context for what you’re trying to achieve more widely then we might be able to suggest an alternative. As for what you’re trying to do, it can’t work because propertyCommon cannot be set to anything other than its default value unless you override it. You can’t override a case class, so you’re scuppered on that front. Maybe you want to make propertyCommon a full property of the case classes or something, but it’s difficult to tell without more information.

Comment: I try to do it in order to represent an elaticsearch index model. I have an Index with a field which is an array of events. The events all have a common structure which is represented by the trait Event, and specificities for each type of event which are represented by case classes. The goal is to map only once commons properties for all types of events

Comment: What about having nested case classes? The outer one would be Event(propertyCommon: String, innerEvent: InnerEvent) and InnerEvent would be a (sealed) trait with case classes Event1 and Event2 implementing it. You would have to do a little extra work deserialising them, but after that you could put whatever copying logic you like on Event without disturbing the inner event. It’s not exactly natural, but it might do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe nested case classes is what I need. I will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you say you want to do is called a prototype pattern in OOP, and as far as I can tell it isn't supported out of the box in Scala (and I think anywhere else).

There are also a few problems:

- `propertyCommon` is not set up using constructor, so each implementation that would have to set it, would most likely have to `override` it using anonymous class (but then, this property will not be a part of equals, hashcode, toString, derivation, etc)
- `Event` doesn't define any interface that would allow updating it

The easiest (and safest) way I see to implement functionality you want, would be something like this:

```
trait Event {
  val propertyCommon: String // will be set by implementing class

  def clone(propertyCommon: String = this.propertyCommon): Event
}

// children define propertyCommon to match the interface
case class EventA(propertyA: String, propertyCommon: String = "") extends Event {
  def clone(propertyCommon: String = this.propertyCommon): EventA = copy(propertyCommon)
}
case class EventB(propertyB: String, propertyCommon: String = "") extends Event {
  def clone(propertyCommon: String = this.propertyCommon): EventB = copy(propertyCommon)
}
```

However, probably if we knew more about your problem we could provide some other, simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I took a simple use case but in reality i have 30 commons properties and 5 case classes which implement the trait Event. I think write a clone method with 30 parameters isn't what i want to do. I explained more of my problem in comments of my original post. I probably need to think the problem differently.